# translate(list1, list2) in prolog

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I was trying a functor translate([3,5,1,3],[three,ﬁve,one,three]) which does the operation of printing numbers. I get a strange warning while executing like this,

35 ?- translate([1,2,3],[a,b,c]).
ERROR: write/2: stream `a' does not exist

```
domains

list1=integer*
list2=symbol*
```

predicates

```
translate(list1,list2)
means(integer,symbol)
```

clauses

```
translate([],[]).

translate([],_):-
    write("\nError in Input").

translate(_,[]):-
    write("\nError in Input").

translate([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2]):-
    write(Head2," = "),
    means(Head1,Name),
    write(Name,"\n"),
    translate(Tail1,Tail2).


means(0,zero).

means(1,one).

means(2,two).

means(3,three).

means(4,four).

means(5,five).

means(6,six).

means(7,seven).

means(8,eight).

means(9,nine).
```

What exactly is the problem? This is the expected value.

translate([1,2,3],[a,b,c])

a = one
b = two
c = three

Yes

Comment: I did retag to `visual-prolog` because I think thats whats being used here (as there are domains and that)

Answer (score 3):

Variables need to be uppercase:

```
translate([1,2,3],[A,B,C]).
```

When you enter the `translate([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2])` clause, `a` unifies with `Head2`, and then you try to satisfy `write(Head2, "=")`, which is `write(a, "=")`.

`write/2` takes as first argument a Stream and writes the second argument to that Stream.

Presumably you want to use - if you want output at all - something like

```
writef('Head2 = %w', [Head2])
```

(I got the formatting from [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.30%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/format.html%27%29%29).)

Comment: i need to print in this case.

Comment: I'm getting this error,
133 ?- translate([0,1], ["zero", "one"]).
Head2 = 122
ERROR: write/2: Domain error: `stream_or_alias' expected, found `[122,101,114,111]'
 134 ?-

Comment: My writef/2 invocation was wrong; I've updated my answer accordingly.